# mysql replication dump data to binlog

Tags: mysql, database-replication

As mysql replication sometimes breaks and it is not possible do recover the replication with the binary logs I would like to know if there is a possibility to dump certain tables or maybe a whole database to the binary log.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, not in moment. you must dump the master and import it into the Slave. Why you cant restart the replication. What is the error ?

Comment: Can you describe how replication breaks? Because there are many settings you can change to make it running better.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers. 
It broke while i was on holiday because of a technical defect on the slave. My collegue said he repaired it, but something must have gone wrong. So i needet to do the offical way, because the binlogs are only stored 10 days (I increased this value)